# Stripe - partial refund with PHP, iOS and Alamofire

Tags: php, json, swift, alamofire, stripe-payments

Hi I get an error of `responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)` I guess this is caused by the amount I passed to my backend server. But, I couldn't find out why. If I process full refund (not using amount and currency), everything works fine.

Below code is in iOS.

```
print(countOrders)
var requestString = "http://xxxxx.com/fullRefund.php"
var params = ["chargeId": chargeId]
let amountStr = String(Int(sellingPrice * Double(quantity)))
if countOrders > 1 {
    requestString = "http://xxxxx.com/partialRefund.php"
    params = ["chargeId": chargeId, "amount": amountStr, "currency": currency]
}
print(requestString)
print(chargeId)
print(amountStr)
print(currency)
Alamofire.request(requestString, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON { (response) in
    switch response.result {
        case .success(_):
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            break
    }
}
```

Every input should be correct as it prints

```
2
http://xxxxx.com/partialRefund.php
ch_1BDdTTLYXQrQQLvfRzXnzLsh
4083
CNY
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)
```

Here is the charge detail from Stripe

```
ID: ch_1BDdTTLYXQrQQLvfRzXnzLsh
Amount: ¥6,366.00 CNY → $7,391.84 HKD
```

Below code is partialRefund.php. I guess something wrong in amount since error shows inputDataNilOrZeroLength

```
<?php
require_once('stripe-php/init.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_keyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy');
$chargeId = $_POST['chargeId'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];           // this line is deleted in fullRefund.php
$currency = $_POST['currency'];       // this line is deleted in fullRefund.php
try {
    $re = \Stripe\Refund::create(
        array(
            "charge" => $chargeId,
            "amount" => $amount*100,  // this line is deleted in fullRefund.php
            "currency" => $currency   // this line is deleted in fullRefund.php
        )
    );
    $json = array(
        'status' => 'Success'
    );
    echo json_encode($json);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $json = array(
        'status' => 'Failure',
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    );
    echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you're getting an error in your response *to* the iOS app, rather than in something coming into your PHP script.  You might want to try [switching to `responseString`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1942) to see if that fixes it, or try adding a Content-Type header before you `echo` your JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: If I use ```responseString``` instead of ```responseJSON```, I can see the response is success, but I can't see the refund is processed in my Stripe dashboard. If I added ```header('Content-Type: application/json');``` before ```echo json_encode($json);```, still fail with same error.

Comment: If I use ```responseString``` and I process full refund, everything is good and I can see the refund processed in Stripe dashboard. So, I am thinking there might be something strange in ```amount```

Comment: The error you mentioned is coming from AlamoFire's handling of the response from your server; if the refund wasn't being processed, then that'd be a different (server-side) error.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I sent an email to Stripe. And they say you can ignore the currency cuz it only refund the original currency they charge